# How to dockerize individual apps inside Hadoop in multi tenant environment?

Tags: hadoop, docker, hadoop-yarn

I have seen HortonWorks put the full Hadoop inside a docker that allows to install Hadoop in different environments. But how about the individual apps inside Hadoop that run on YARN? Especially in a multi-tenant environment, this would be useful.

Appreciate any thoughts on how to achieve this.